# Calling Controller method which is in sub directory via Termial/CLI - codeigniter4

Tags: php, routes, command-line-interface, url-routing, codeigniter-4

My Folder structure is like below in my CI4 Application

```
App/Controllers
    -- Folder1
        Controller1.php
        Controller2.php
    Controller.php
    AnotherController.php
```

From [Codeigniter 4 Docs](https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/cli/cli.html#cli-only-routing), I know I can call my controller from a terminal like below

```
$ cd /path/to/project/public
$ php index.php tools message
```

But How do I call a controller in Sub-directory from terminal

```
$ cd /path/to/project/public
$ php index.php Folder1 Controller1 method
```

Answer (score 0):

Either make explicit routes that lead to the "subcontrollers" or just use the fully-qualified namespace in your CLI statement:

`php index.php '\App\Controllers\Folder1\Controller1' SomeMethod`

This assumes that you've correctly namespaced `Controller1`.